# Injecting a set of files in a Thymeleaf template while keeping the amount of tags at a minimum

Tags: html, template, thymeleaf

I use a Thymeleaf template to inject a set of files (which contain precalculated HTML) into one big HTML. The files with their metadata are stored in a map called `files`, the files content is stored in another map called `content`. Both maps share the same key which is basically an id of the files.

The relevant section of the template has these lines:

```
<div th:each="f : ${files}" th:id="${f.key}">
    <h1 th:text="${f.value.pageTitle}"></h1>
        [(${content[ f.key ]})]
</div>
```

The result after this template was processed is:

```
<div id="1">
    <h1>Title of document with ID 1</h1>
    Content of file with ID 1
</div>
<div id="2">
    <h1>Title of document with ID 2</h1>
    Content of file with ID 2
</div>
```

This works fine but in order to place the `th:each` I had to introduce a superfluous `div`. Can I get rid of the div in the template and have a result like this:

```
<h1>Title of document with ID 1</h1>
Content of file with ID 1
<h1>Title of document with ID 2</h1>
Content of file with ID 2
```

Comment: Have you tried `th:remove="tag"` in the `div` element? https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#removing-template-fragments

Comment: @aventurin This looks promising, I will give it a try. I read the tutorial but overlooked this section.

Comment: @Aventurin I can confirm this is working. Do you want to turn your comment into an answer ?

Comment: @Marget I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf has a mechanism for [removing template fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#removing-template-fragments). You can use the `th:remove="tag"` attribute to remove the containing tag but not its children:

```
<div th:each="f : ${files}" th:remove="tag">
    <h1 th:text="${f.value.pageTitle}"></h1>
    [(${content[ f.key ]})]
</div>
```

The resulting output will not contain the `div` but the `h1` element and the text node.